# using the environment variable, Firebase invalid api key error in console

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I am using Google Sign In, Firebase, and React firebase hook to login react web application.
inserting firebaseConfig API (.env.local) file and setting the secret keys to firebase config causes errors on the console

**.env.local**

````
REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN=doctors-portal-6bc13.firebaseapp.com
REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID=doctors-portal-6bc13
REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET=doctors-portal-6bc13.appspot.com
REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=725454304359
REACT_APP_APP_ID=1:725454304359:web:49840cbf09a6b578e210c2```
````

**firebase.init.js file**

````
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

 const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
   authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
   projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
   storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
   messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
   appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
 };


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth(app);
export default auth;```
````

**Works directly when using Firebase API without using (.env.local)**

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyA72Jfi_WXWie-i641mAYhLv3QgiynzLxQ",
  authDomain: "doctors-portal-6bc13.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "doctors-portal-6bc13",
  storageBucket: "doctors-portal-6bc13.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "725454304359",
  appId: "1:725454304359:web:49840cbf09a6b578e210c2",
};
```

writting like this does not give any error

Comment: I don't see any API key in your `.env` file?

Answer (score 3):

try this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH4Dm.png
You have to place your .env path between `${

It works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

You just need to Restart the Server.
Close the server and start again with ***npm start***.
This just worked fine for me.

(Every time you create or change anything in your **.env** file, you need to start the server again )

Comment: I think the problem was solved int he comment he was missing a variable in the .env file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).